# How many proteoforms are theoretically possible?

Tags: proteins, protein-folding, proteomics

Initially, I was going to ask how many proteins were possible. But, while researching the question, I learned the word proteoform and have been reading a lot of stuff I don't really understand, but from I do think I get,  the word "proteoform" was created because sometimes the "typical" or "canonical" forms of a "protein" can take different forms, or "proteoforms" based on environmental and possibly other factors, despite being coded for with the same DNA. So, a "protein" will often (always?) have several different "proteoforms". As I understand it, it is part of the protein-folding problem, and the complexity is huge. I was trying to see if anyone has calculated or figured out what would be needed to calculate how many proteoforms were possible, but I don't find anything. I imagine the number is tremendous, I just wanted to know how tremendous. So, how many proteoforms are possible? If that's not known,  what would be needed to know this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate?: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108908/is-there-are-theoretical-limit-to-the-number-of-proteins-possible-and-their-resp I know this is about *proteins* rather than "*proteoforms*", but the distinction does not seem particularly important at scales like this.

Comment: @BryanKrause I think the question is a duplicate, at least in the sense that the question+answer note the existence of isoforms/alternate structures making the upper bound of the answer huge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there are theoretical limit to the number of proteins possible and their respective structure?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108908/is-there-are-theoretical-limit-to-the-number-of-proteins-possible-and-their-resp)